# ¿Como puedo saber que checkbox están marcados dependiendo el registro de la B.D en codegniter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Al querer actualizar, los checkbox que están marcados en la base de datos, no me muestran como marcados al momento de actualizar 
[image: Checkbox]
.

```
<?php  foreach($respuestas as $r): ?>
 <?php if($value->id_pregunta == $r->id_pregunta):?>
  <?php if($value->id_pregunta == 1):?>
    <?php if($r->id_respuestas == TRUE): ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="inline-checkbox-cs">
            <label><input name="id_respuestas1[]" id="id_respuesta1"  value="<?= $r->id_respuestas >" 
            class="checkbox-inline i-checks pull-left" type="checkbox"> <?= $r->respuesta ?> </label>
       </div>
    </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ponerle el atributo checked al checkbox para que aparezca seleccionado:

[W3Schools Atributo checked](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

En el ejemplo del link verás que la 3ª opción está seleccionada porque el checkbox tiene el atributo checked

Comment: Hola , muchas gracias por contestar. Le he puesto el atributo checked, pero solamente me aparecen los checkbox que tiene un dato, si tiene nullo ese checkbox no se puesta. ¿A que se debe esto? Me podrias ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, tienes un error en tu código, tienes que cambiar esto:

```
<label>
  <input name="id_respuestas1[]" id="id_respuesta1"  value="<?= $r->id_respuestas >"
         class="checkbox-inline i-checks pull-left" type="checkbox"> 
  <?= $r->respuesta ?> 
</label>
```

Por esto:

```
<label>
  <input name="id_respuestas1[]" id="id_respuesta1"  value="<?= $r->id_respuestas ?>"
         class="checkbox-inline i-checks pull-left" type="checkbox"> 
  <?= $r->respuesta ?> 
</label>
```

Ya que en el **Value** no cerraste con `?>` solo pusiste `>`. Después para poder hacer que tus **Checkbox** se estén marcados se utiliza **Checked**.

Estas haciendo uso de 3 validaciones que seria lo mismo que:

```
<?php foreach($respuestas as $r){
if($value->id_pregunta == $r->id_pregunta && $value->id_pregunta == 1 && $r->id_respuestas == TRUE){ ?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="inline-checkbox-cs">
    <label>
      <input name="id_respuestas1[]" id="id_respuesta1"  value="<?= $r->id_respuestas ?>"
             class="checkbox-inline i-checks pull-left" type="checkbox"> 
      <?= $r->respuesta ?> 
    </label>
  </div>
<?php }} ?>
```

Entonces viendo tu comentario en otra respuesta, la cuestión por la que no te salen los datos que tienen null es porque simplemente no se cumple la condición, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es usar **else**, si cumple tu condición lo muestras `checked` y si no lo muestras solo.

```
<?php foreach ($respuestas as $r) {
    if ($value->id_pregunta == $r->id_pregunta && $value->id_pregunta == 1 && $r->id_respuestas == true) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="inline-checkbox-cs">
                <label><input name="id_respuestas1[]" id="id_respuesta1" value="<?= $r->id_respuestas ?>" 
                              class="checkbox-inline i-checks pull-left" type="checkbox" checked> <?= $r->respuesta ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="inline-checkbox-cs">
                <label><input name="id_respuestas1[]" id="id_respuesta1" value="<?= $r->id_respuestas ?>" 
                              class="checkbox-inline i-checks pull-left" type="checkbox"> <?= $r->respuesta ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar. Cuando lo pongo en esa estructura no me manda la vista con estilos, ¿Crees que es la forma de escribir Foreach?

Comment: Pues más bien ve las clases que estas utilizando y que tus divs estén cerrados correctamente, porque así debe de funcionar sin problema alguno.